# Firebase - Issue during deployment getting error : Error: An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

When i test my application using the below command in the localhost, it works fine.

```
firebase serve --only functions,hosting
```

But when i tried to deploy it using below command. It fails with error message (Error: An unexpected error has occurred.). Does not give much details

```
firebase deploy
```

or

```
firebase deploy --only functions,hosting
```

Initial error was to update firebase-functions and firebase-admin so i went ahead and updated it after reading the guide in below link. Iam not using any of those features.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@5.11.0 --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Here is the output using command : firebase deploy --debug

```
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.734Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.739Z] Command:       C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase deploy --only functions,hosting
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.740Z] CLI Version:   3.18.4
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.740Z] Platform:      win32
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.740Z] Node Version:  v8.10.0
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.741Z] Time:          Tue May 15 2018 00:29:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.741Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.759Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.762Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.765Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:35.766Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token  
 { refresh_token: '1/V2t23LrBy9dznRfmTQnnh-0x3k3RrWFiA2EbNwRErOU',
  client_id: '563584335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pr03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret: 'j9iVZfS8kkCEFUPaAeJV0sAi',
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  scope: 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase openid' } 
 Tue May 15 2018 00:29:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:36.385Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:36.393Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/stashit-7885bob  

 Tue May 15 2018 00:29:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:37.606Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:37.607Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/stashit-7885bob/tokens  

 Tue May 15 2018 00:29:37 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:38.662Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'stashit-7885bob'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying functions, hosting
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:46.087Z] > [functions] package.json contents: {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "ejs": "^2.5.9",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase": "^5.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
[info] i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:46.087Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/projectSettings/stashit-7885bob?view=CONSUMER_VIEW  

 Tue May 15 2018 00:29:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:46.092Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/projectSettings/stashit-7885bob?view=CONSUMER_VIEW  

 Tue May 15 2018 00:29:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:48.558Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:48.586Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] +  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:48.588Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/stashit-7885bob  

 Tue May 15 2018 00:29:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:50.672Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:50.673Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com/v1/projects/288692255744:getServerAppConfig  

 Tue May 15 2018 00:29:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:51.783Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-05-14T18:59:52.294Z] TypeError: Path must be a string. Received [ 'public/',
  'public/css',
  'public/js',
  'public/mdb-css',
  'public/mdb-js',
  'functions/js',
  'public/images' ]
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:211:7)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\resolveProjectPath.js:7:15)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\hosting\prepare.js:31:39)
    at _chain (C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\index.js:26:38)
    at C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\index.js:29:14
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

And my firebase.json file looks like this

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": ["public/", "public/css", "public/js", "public/mdb-css", "public/mdb-js", "functions/js", "public/images"],
    "rewrites":[
      {"source" : "/timestamp", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/stashlogin", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/stash", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/get", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/put", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/categorycolor", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/category", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/category/**", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/put/**", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/delete/**", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/profile", "function" : "app"},
      {"source" : "/feedback", "function" : "app"}
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please let me know how to proceed as there is not reason for the error message. I am actually stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `public` directory must be a single string, not an array.

Comment: Usage of arrays for public enabled me to just specify the script or css files without having to mention the path of the files where they are. It was sort of easy and awesome. 

I will try the above single string approach today. Just wanted to know above approach sort of looks like, i have to put all the .CSS, images, .JS(third-party files) to put in same folder, is it the best practice and approach.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, moving all the .CSS & .JS files to single folder helped me resolve the error.

Comment: I also replaced entire rewrites with below code as in one of youtube firecast videos. 
`"rewrites":[
      {"source" : "**", "function" : "app"}`
    ]`